# How to parse a specific part of web-page in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, substring, html-parsing

I'm fetching a body of a web-page where there is a table with a lot of lines, like this:

```
 ...
 ...
 <tbody>
   <tr class="odd">
     <td align="center">08:00</td>
     <td align="center">9.50</td>
     <td>Description of event 1 </td>
     <td align="center">7.80</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="even">
     <td align="center">09:00</td>
     <td align="center">11.10</td>
     <td>Description of event 2</td>
     <td align="center">27.40</td>
   </tr>
...
```

I would like to cut parts from this table and parse it to my object. I was trying to use substring but I don't know where is the needed part of the text. Also, I was looking for regular expression and different parsers. How can I decide my issue? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, when you say "cut string", do you mean [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: You should use an html parser. Take a look at https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse your html to a `Document` and use the [Jsoup DOM methods](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) to navigate your html.

```
String yourHtml = "<someHtml/>"; 
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(yourHtml);

Element table = doc.getElementByTag("tbody");
Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {
    for (Element cell : row.getElementsByTag("td")) {
        String content = cell.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `content` variable defined when you're getting your rows? Should this be `table`?

Comment: @byxor whoops, thats whats happening when you code on the stackoverflow page isntead of a real IDE

Answer (score 1):

As it is in XML format, you should do by Java XML API such DOM or SAX. Or you could use Third Party XML library such as JDOM and DOM4J for the processing.

```
File file = new File(Appl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("testing.xml").getFile());
Document document = DocumentFactory.createDocument(file);
Element element = document.getElementById("tag22");
System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
```

**testing.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tag1 id="tag1">
    <tag2 id="tag22">Testing Content</tag2>
</tag1>
```